# Do all of the assigned workflow tasks need to be complete in order for the workflow to continue working?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, parallel-processing, action

I have built a workflow in SharePoint Designer and put two "collect data from user" actions as parallel actions in the same step.

Do both of the users need to complete their tasks in order for the workflow to continue to its next step?

If both of them are needed, how can I build the workflow so that both users have tasks but only one of them need to complete the task to make the workflow continue?

Answer (score 0):

Activities on all branches will need to complete before the workflow continues. There are ways in which you could achieve what you want. Probably the best way is to use a ConditionedActivityGroup (CAG) activity.

Set the collect data activities as individual child activities, with the WhenCondition set to a condition that returns true if the user has not yet submitted data. Then set the UntilCondition to return true if at least one activity has completed.